# How to set tax code on Vendor Credits expense item using NetSuite SuiteTalk SOAP api or SuiteScripts?

Tags: netsuite, suitescript, suitetalk

How to set tax code on Vendor Credits expense item?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mfCCM.png)

Tax code for expense item can be changed manually by the user, so how to set this value using NetSuite SuiteTalk SOAP api or SuiteScripts  ?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.